# Node build failing

Tags: xcode, node.js, gcc, homebrew

I am on Mac OS X 10.6 - I tried installing node via homebrew and it was failing with a non descriptive error message. I decided to clone the node repo and building it within the directory. After running the ./configure command, the output is:

```
Checking for program g++ or c++          : /usr/bin/g++ 
Checking for program cpp                 : /usr/bin/cpp 
Checking for program ar                  : /usr/bin/ar 
Checking for program ranlib              : /usr/bin/ranlib 
Checking for g++                         : ok  
Checking for program gcc or cc           : /usr/bin/gcc 
Checking for gcc                         : ok  
Checking for library dl                  : yes 
Checking for openssl                     : not found 
Checking for function SSL_library_init   : yes 
Checking for header openssl/crypto.h     : yes 
Checking for library util                : yes 
Checking for library rt                  : not found 
Checking for fdatasync(2) with c++       : no 
'configure' finished successfully (2.180s)
```

When running the 'make' , the build fails and I get this error:

```
System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Headers/Carbon.h:70:35: error: SecurityHI/SecurityHI.h: No such file or directory
Waf: Leaving directory `/Users/topica/rails_projects/node/out'
Build failed:  -> task failed (err #1): 
    {task: cxx platform_darwin.cc -> platform_darwin_5.o}
make: *** [program] Error 1
```

Even though openssl says "not found" the headers were found, but to be safe I re-ran configure with this command: ./configure --openssl-includes=/opt/local/include and openssl but still got the same error.

I did install gcc the other day, the output from gcc -v is:

```
Using built-in specs.
Target: i686-apple-darwin10
Configured with: /var/tmp/gcc/gcc-5666.3~123/src/configure --disable-checking --enable-       werror --prefix=/usr --mandir=/share/man --enable-languages=c,objc,c++,obj-c++ --program-   transform-name=/^[cg][^.-]*$/s/$/-4.2/ --with-slibdir=/usr/lib --build=i686-apple-darwin10 -  -program-prefix=i686-apple-darwin10- --host=x86_64-apple-darwin10 --target=i686-apple-darwin10 --with-gxx-include-dir=/include/c++/4.2.1
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)
```

Maybe there is some conflict with my xcode install and gcc? Or something else entirely. I've been at it for days and haven't been able to find any answers. Let me know what other information is needed

UPDATE: Here is the console output when running ./configure --openssl-includes=/opt/local/include

```
Checking for program g++ or c++          : /usr/bin/g++ 
Checking for program cpp                 : /usr/bin/cpp 
Checking for program ar                  : /usr/bin/ar 
Checking for program ranlib              : /usr/bin/ranlib 
Checking for g++                         : ok  
Checking for program gcc or cc           : /usr/bin/gcc 
Checking for gcc                         : ok  
Checking for library dl                  : yes 
Checking for function SSL_library_init   : yes 
Checking for header openssl/crypto.h     : yes 
Checking for library util                : yes 
Checking for library rt                  : not found 
Checking for fdatasync(2) with c++       : no 
'configure' finished successfully (0.660s)
```

Comment: I'm definitely not an expert on this but it sounds like something odd within the Carbon framework.  Can you verify that there is a SecurityHI.h file at the location: /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Frameworks/SecurityHI.framework/Headers?  (Since it found Carbon.h, I'd think your include path is OK.)

Comment: hmm.. /Headers does not exist. I'm not sure why. Should I just find a copy somewhere and include them?

Comment: I don't know what the fix would be, honestly.  If the SecurityHI.framework is there but no headers, I wonder if the folder was accidentally moved.  Does Spotlight (or whatever) detect a SecurityHI.h anywhere?  (On my system that framework folder includes contents: CodeResources, Headers, Resources, SecurityHI, Versions.)

Comment: I found a Headers directory in     /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework  . I tried running cp -R Headers /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Frameworks/SecurityHI.framework/ and got: cp: symlink: Versions/A/Headers: Permission denied

Comment: The Headers directory I found contains Carbon.h and Carbon.r which were referenced in the error message so it seems like the right one. Any idea on how to copy this over?

Comment: No, the Carbon framework Headers and the embedded SecurityHI ones are different things.  The Headers in the SecurityHI framework should contain things like SecurityHI.h (which it was complaining about) and others: KeychainHI.h, SecCertificateSupport.h, URLAccess.h.

Comment: I did some checking on another machine here and it looks as if the files you're missing are part of an Xcode installation.

Comment: thanks so much for your debugging help. I ended up registering at the apple dev site and downloading a version of xcode for 10.6.8. This fixed the issues. I thought gcc would have been enough but I may not have configured things correctly. thanks again!

Comment: I don't agree this is too localized @Abizern ...this issue applies to anyone trying to install software via Homebrew on older versions of OS X (eg Snow Leopard 10.6.8). There are no clear instructions for how to do this I could find so this question is useful

Comment: My experience: osx-gcc-installer is not enough for Homebrew to work. Apple no longer provide XCode 4.x or XCode Command Line tools for Snow Leopard (apparently it's available if you have a *paid* Developer account). You can however install XCode 3.2.6 for free. Homebrew complains XCode is out of date but it was able to install the packages I needed like git and python